# Hexahedral expansion diagram

Tags: 3d

### Problem

What should I do if I want to use Flutter to write an Android app that can recognize whether hexahedral unfolding images are correct?

### My Idea

At present, my idea is to use Yolo for image recognition and localization, and then cut, but I don't know how to do the rest because I haven't learned much about computer science Can you give me a clue?

### Game Rules

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO7r8.png)

On the left is a hexahedral expansion diagram, and on the right, choose an answer that matches the expansion diagram on the left